# Whats the purpose and impact on performance of prototypeItem for ListView on Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

There's an attribute I still don't understand for `ListView` on flutter: `prototypeItem`.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/prototypeItem.html

## Questions

- What kind of widgets should we return here? Maybe a `SizedBox`?
- Can someone show an example of its usage and how to measure the impact of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation is enough exhaustive.

> **If non-null, forces the children to have the same extent as the given widget**
> in the scroll direction.
> **Specifying an prototypeItem is more efficient than letting the children
> determine their own extent** because the scrolling machinery can make use of
> the foreknowledge of the children's extent to save work, for example when
> the scroll position changes drastically.

So with `prototypeItem` performances could improve.
It tells the `ListView` what to expect and this seems to save performances with Flutter. The `prototypeItem` could be any widget you would need: `SizedBox`, `Container`, `Cards` and others

Comment: thanks for that, are there any code examples about it?

Comment: Didn't find searching online. Consider you can use any type of Widget to build your prototypeItem so I wouldn't bother too much finding examples. @DanielGomezRico

Comment: It would be lovely to find a way to measure how much the performance improves using that

Comment: One way you could possibly test that is so create a list with 1k or more items, and compare the performances between the two ways. Loading the ListView with and without prototypeItem, and check UI / widget builds times.

Comment: It's not exhaustive since I'm sure many people don't know what 'extent' is like me. If I give it example content, that's not to say the content can't be longer. It doesn't explain what it uses it for properly.

Comment: @Dominic any edit is appreciated! Feel free to add more info.